# The inverse of a fractional ideal is a fractional ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, integral-domain

> Let $A$ be an integral domain and $K$ its field of fractions. If $M$ is a non-zero fractional ideal of $A$, then $$N=\{x \in K : xM \subseteq A\}$$
>   is also a fractional ideal of $A$.

The proof I am trying to follow is given in Dummit and Foote.

I agree that it is easy to check that $N$ is an $A$-submodule of $K$.

The next part of the proof goes as follows:

"By definition, there exists some $d \in A\setminus\{0\}$ such that $dM\subseteq A$ and so $M$ contains non-zero elements of $A$."

I really can't see how this follows - any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I'm just being dense but it's driving me crazy!

Comment: I do not think your definition implies what Dummit and Foote says. For instance, let $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $K = \mathbb{Q} = M$. Then there does not exists a non zero integer $d$ such that $d \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$. But I think the conclusion is fine.

Comment: By definition, a fractional ideal of $A$ is an $A$-submodule $M$ of $K$ such that $a M \subseteq A$ for some $0 \neq a \in A$.  In particular, we cannot take $M = \mathbb{Q}$ as this is not a fractional ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I see. You are right about that. According to the definition $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a fractional ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M\ne 0$ and thus there is $x\in M$, $x\ne 0$. What about $dx$? (In fact, you don't need $dM\subset A$ in order to find a non-zero element in $M$ which is also in $A$: write $x=a/b$ with $a,b\ne 0$, and notice that $bx=a\in M\cap A$.)

**Edit.** In order to conclude that $N$ is a fractional ideal note that $(dx)N\subseteq A$, and we are done.

Comment: Ah ok - I stupidly forgot that $M$ is an $A$-submodule. Thank you!